# sessionfactory, beans and multiple xml-config files

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

Spring 3.2.0 release, Hibernate. Exception -

> class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL
>   because it does not exist

File path - src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml

This destination and file template was autogenerated by Intellij IDEA. Google tell me, that one of solution - delete classpath prefix, but i have no file with this propety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it to `src/main/resources` instead

Comment: thx, now i meet other error with datasource.
 Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doCloseConnection(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljavax/sql/DataSource;)V

Comment: You have different version of DataSourceUtils in classpath which doesn't have this method